# How to deactivate a liferay user for particular organization?

Tags: liferay, portlet, liferay-6

I have a requirement to deactivate a user for a particular organization.In liferay we deactivate the user directly by control panel under users tool.if i deactivate,The user will deactivate in portal level so it is applicable to all organizations not to particular organization.so can i do manual code for this or is there any alternative by default?

Answer (score 1):

User Management in Liferay is global - to the whole portal. You authenticate to the portal, thus a deactivated user can't be authenticated to the portal.

You can make users members of Organizations or site - and this membership (or other organization- or site-level roles) can be used to provide them with permissions.

If you want them to be able to sign in, don't deactivate them. If you don't want them to access a certain organization, make the content of that organization available to members only - and exclude the user from the members of that organization.

Answer (score 0):

OK you could do this in code level ,

> ```
> User singleUser=UserLocalServiceUtil.getUser(userId)
> singleUser.setStatus(WorkflowConstants.STATUS_DENIED);
> UserLocalServiceUtil.updateUser(singleUser);
> ```

So basically setting **User** **Status** to either `WorkflowConstants.STATUS_DENIED`, `WorkflowConstants.STATUS_EXPIRED` or `WorkflowConstants.STATUS_INACTIVE` will do the work of deactivating particular **User**.

*But you need to research on the aftermath effect of these status field.*

Comment: will this code works for deactivating a user for a particular organization not for entire portal?

Comment: Sorry , i got it wrong. It will deactivate that user at global level. And BTW what do you mean by organization level ?

Comment: in liferay we have hierarchy like organizations,communities like that.